# В каких случаях возникает потребность использования raw pointers в современном C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

После появления новых возможностей в C++ таких как `std::make_shared()` и `std::make_unique` то возникает вопрос : А есть ли хоть один случай, когда действительно нужно работать с сырым указателем?

В этом вопросе я не учитываю случаи, когда стороняя библиотека в каком-либо из методов принимает указатель.

Я беру среднего по уровню программиста на C++. Он пишет свою библиотеку без использования сторонего кода. И у меня не находится ни одного примера, когда ему действительно нужно пользоваться сырыми указателями.

Comment: Можно обратиться к первому полю структуру типа int через сырой указатель вот так: *(int *) struct_ptr, а потом угорать с непонимания C++ мартышек

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что *среднему программисту* стоит писать свои *библиотеки* на крестах.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Во внутренних деталях реализации, когда владеющие указатели усложняют взаимодействие, когда нужно разделять владение, но время жизни объекта чётко детерминировано и не возникает вопроса: где и когда чистить объект (`shared_ptr` в таких случаях - лишнее), когда ссылкой не обойтись, потому как возможна ситуация с `nullptr` у объекта. В публичных API стараться избегать, пока это возможно, либо чётко обосновывать - "почему?" и "зачем?".

В общем, я придерживаюсь правила: обходиться без сырых указателей, пока это возможно. Пока не подводило (embedded).

Кстати, возможно забавно, но в C проектах, при достижении определённого уровня сложности, тоже начинают появляются механизмы разделяемого владения. Это всем известные `xxx_ref(object)`/`xxx_unref(object)`. Примеры: GLib со своим gobject, FFmpeg активно внедряет подсчёт ссылок для AVPacket и AVFrame (для таких случаев в Boost существует `intrusive_ptr`), ядро Linux тоже не стоит в стороне (https://lwn.net/Articles/336224/ по слову Reference Counting или http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch17lev1sec7) со своим `kobject`.

Answer (score 13):

Самый банальный пример — дерево. Каждый узел хранит родителя. Можно, конечно, хранить в `weak_ptr`, но это не удобно и, на мой взгляд, глупо. Поэтому в этом случае используется «голый» указатель. Можно придумать и другие примеры, но суть их будет следующая: «голые» указатели, в современном коде, можно и нужно использовать тогда, когда мы не владеем тем, на что ссылаемся и у нас есть уверенность, что то, на что мы ссылаемся не «умрёт» раньше, чем мы.

---

На эту тему есть отличное видео от Страуструпа: [Writing Good C++14](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OEu9C51K2A). Львиная его доля посвящена именно указателям.

Comment: @Abyx, можно node сделать наследником `enable_shared_from_this` и всех потомков хранить в `shared_ptr`, а вот как хранить родителя это уже выбор — либо «голый», либо `weak_ptr`

Answer (score 11):

Упомянутые "умные" указатели являются владеющими. Т.е. при вызове деструктора умного указателя данные либо освобождаются сразу (`std::unique_ptr`), либо уменьшается счетчик владения (`std::shared_ptr`), и при достижении нуля осуществляется освобождение данных.

Если же указатель не владеет данными как раз имеет смысл использовать сырые указатели. Небольшое исключение это `std::weak_ptr` - невладеющий указатель, но полученный из `std::shared_ptr`.

Чаще всего наверное использовать сырые указатели приходится при взаимодействии со старым (до `C++11`) кодом или вовсе Си-кодом. Например, работа со строками `char*`.

Comment: Что такое smart pointers мне известно. Вопрос в другом: Что если нет нужды использовать сторонний код и legacy код, то что может вынудить программиста использовать raw указатели? Ничего. Так?

Comment: @sys_dev нет. Не так. Например, если нужно использовать `dynamic_cast` он вернет сырой указатель (ну или ссылку). При работе с массивами могут потребоваться указатели. Главное, что стоит иметь в виду, что сырой указатель - это максимальная производительность. Умные указатели, в большинстве случаев - это overhead.

Comment: Всегда считал, что если человеку потребовалось использовать `dynamic_cast`, то он плохо подумал над способом решения своей проблемы

Comment: @sys_dev в большинстве случаев это наверное действительно так. Но софт обычно не создается полностью с нуля, а использует готовые (не только стандартные) библиотеки и фреймворки, в которых могут быть функции (обработчики с фиксированной сигнатурой), принимающие указатель на базовый класс. И в этом обработчике надо (придется) сделать `dynamic_cast`, т.к. производный класс добавляет новые функции, которых просто не было в базовом.

Comment: @alexolut, [dynamic_pointer_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)

Comment: @ixSci с `shared_ptr` безусловно имеет смысл, но уже с `unique_ptr` придется получать "сырой" указатель, и делать классический `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @alexolut, ну с `unique` проще, в том плане, что можно сделать `release` у одного и инициализировать другой, результатом `dynamic_cast`, тем самым ни на каком этапе «владение» не теряется.

Comment: @ixSci чтобы сделать `release` это надо архитектурно разрешить сначала. А если передаём, скажем, `const unique_ptr<T>&`, то освободить не получится вовсе.

Answer (score 4):

Хотите простейший пример? :)

```
int main(int , char**)
```

Обойтись можно без многого, просто бывают ситуации, когда этот обход куда дольше, чем прямая дорога.

Answer (score 2):

Те же `std::shared_ptr<T>` занимают в два раза больше памяти (из-за указателя на счетчик). Для структур (деревьев, например), активно использующих указатели, это может быть значительной добавкой. Да и передача их по значению - это копирование в стек в два раза большего объёма данных.
Да, в больших проектах часто не так заметно будет это потребление памяти, но бывают и исключительные ситуации.

Comment: Ошибся, указатель на счетчик, конечно