# Определить можно ли удалить объект

Tags: c++, ооп, память

Как известно, в C++ можно создать объект как глобальную или локальную переменную. В этом случае компилятор сам заботится об уничтожении объекта (при выходе из блока или при завершении программы), а вызывать по отношению к нему delete категорически нельзя (иначе может освободиться память, которую освобождать нельзя). А можно создать объект с помощью new (placement new не рассматриваем). В этом случае вся ответственность по освобождению памяти ложится на программиста и в какой-то момент он обязан сделать delete по отношению к объекту, иначе будет утечка памяти.

Допустим, мы создаём объект, который знает, когда он становится ненужным и мы хотели бы, чтобы он сделал delete this в этом случае. Вопрос: может ли объект как-то сам определить, нужно ли делать delete или он выделен не из кучи и поэтому ничего делать нельзя? Разумеется, можно передать в конструктор флаг, который будет сохранён в объекте и использован при удалении, чтобы решить что делать. Однако в этом случае программист становится ответственным за передачу верного значения параметра в зависимости от того как описана переменная, а это неудобно. Нет ли решений лучше?

Comment: использовать std::unique_ptr или другой умный указатель (или написать свой, если требования очень специфичные), собственно в c++11 и выше применять голые указатели в стиле C вообще не рекомендуется.

Comment: @strangeqargo на счет не применять вообще это уж слишком :) Вот если про владение, то да. Кстати, был [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500062/%d0%92-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-raw-pointers-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-c) по этой теме.

Answer (score 2):

Так сказать, освобождая всех от ответственности за мои слова... :)

Пожалуй, что без накладных расходов - никак. В каком-нибудь конкретном компиляторе, возможно, и можно определить, в каком сегменте памяти находится адрес, но это будут еще те накладные расходы...

Можно поковырять диспетчер памяти - опять же, для конкретного компилятора, может быть, вся динамическая память имеет адреса "не меньше, чем".

Все это как минимум непереносимо.

Можно поиграться - я когда-то так утечку искал - переопределить `new`, чтоб он в список вносил выделенные адреса. Тогда возможность удаления определяется как наличие адреса в этом списке.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Исключительно в порядке бреда исключительно для однопоточного... Ну и еще с массой ограничений типа порядка инициализации глобальных переменных :)

```
class Test {
public:
    Test():deletable(lastIsDeletable) { lastIsDeletable = false;
                                        cout << __func__ << endl; }
    ~Test()                           { cout << __func__ << endl; }

    static bool lastIsDeletable;

    void who() const { cout << "I'm " << (deletable ? "" : "non ") << "deletable\n"; }

    void * operator new(size_t n) { cout << __func__ << endl;
        lastIsDeletable = true; return ::new unsigned char[n];
    }

    private:
        bool deletable;
};

bool Test::lastIsDeletable = false;

Test t1;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test * t = new Test;
    t1.who();
    t->who();

}
```

Comment: Можно использовать локальные переменные потока для хранения флага (например, pthread_setspecific/pthread_getspecific). Я думаю, мы можем иметь гарантию, что выделение памяти и вызов конструктора будут выполнены одним и тем же потоком  и между ними в рамках этого потока больше ничего не делается (ибо и выделение памяти, и вызов конструктора выполняется оператором new, а программист даже не узнает адрес объекта, пока не отработает конструктор). В итоге мы получим нормальную поддержку многопоточности. Я прав?

Comment: Опять же, насколько я понимаю, глобальные переменные типа bool будут сразу записаны в секцию данных исполняемого файла, а значит будут инициализированы до вызова любого конструктора. Вызовы же конструкторов явно будут однопоточными, стандарт лишь не гарантирует порядок вызова конструкторов из разных юнитов трансляции.

Comment: Не настолько хорошо ориентируюсь в многопоточности, чтобы уверенно ответить да или нет...

Comment: Кстати, а что если делать deletable = true внутри переопределённого оператора new (разумеется, сначала скастовать указатель к нашему классу)? Или это UB?

Comment: @kiv_apple Я же написал - в порядке бреда... :) Это так. заготовка, за которую я ни коим образом не собираюсь отвечать :)

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно запретить создание объекта класса на стеке, то для этого достаточно сделать конструктор приватным, и создание объектов производить через специальную функцию:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    ~Foo();
    static Foo* createFoo()
    {
        return new Foo();
    }
private:
    Foo();
    Foo(const Foo&);
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&);
};
```

Код позаимствован из [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/124904/3240681) на enSO.

Answer (score 1):

Этому вопросу посвящено правило 27 в книге Скотта Майерса More Effective C. Там он рассматривает различные способы как решить эту проблему. Рекомендую к прочтению, если не всю книгу, то хотя бы эту главу. Автор там предлагает создать такой класс.

```
class HeapTracked{
    typedef void* RawAddress;
    static std::list<RawAddress> addresses;
public:
    class MissingAdress{};
    virtual ~HeapTracked() = 0;
    static void* operator new(std::size_t size){
        void *memPtr = ::operator new(size);
        addresses.push_front(memPtr);
        return memPtr;
    }
    static void operator delete(void *ptr){
        std::list<RawAddress>::iterator it = std::find(addresses.begin(), addresses.end(), ptr);
        if(it != addresses.end()){
            addresses.erase(it);
            ::operator delete(ptr);
        }
        else{
            throw MissingAdress();
        }

    }
    bool isOnHeap() const{
        const void *rawAddress = dynamic_cast<const void*>(this);
        std::list<RawAddress>::iterator it = std::find(addresses.begin(), addresses.end(), rawAddress);   
        return it != addresses.end();
    }
};
HeapTracked::~HeapTracked(){}
std::list<HeapTracked::RawAddress> HeapTracked::addresses;
```

И наследоваться от него теми классами, которым нужно знать в куче они или нет. В приведенном коде все более-менее понятно, кроме этого

```
const void *rawAddress = dynamic_cast<const void*>(this);
```

Тут используется одно интересное свойство `dynamic_cast`. Если применить `dynamic_cast` к указателю на `void`, то мы получим указатель на начало памяти объекта, на который он ссылается. Таким образом, приведение `this` к `const void*` дает указатель на начало текущего объекта.
[Пример](http://cpp.sh/5gkis)

Comment: О, то, что я написал - *"Можно поиграться - я когда-то так утечку искал - переопределить `new`, чтоб он в список вносил выделенные адреса. Тогда возможность удаления определяется как наличие адреса в этом списке."*. Как Журден, который внезапно узнал, что говорил прозой :)